# Hide a fixed position DIV using @media display:none

Tags: css, css-position

The div in question is:

```
  .fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

What I want is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px){
.fixed { display: none; }
}
```

However apparently that's not how fixed containers work?

So how can I hide a "sticky" container when the screen gets resized to something too small to display both the container and the main content and thus making the container overlap the content?

Comment: Your solution should work.  Is another rule overriding your `display: none;`?

Comment: Yup, it works! No idea why it didn't work before. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your css code seems to be working fine, perhaps there is a rule that has more importance/weight than the one in your media query, add `!importat` and see if it works:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 720px){
    .fixed { display: none !important; }
}
```